# Can't understand why loop is not updating variable value

Tags: java

When I create this method to find the index of the smallest number in an array starting from a specific index, it keeps returning 0 no matter which numbers are in the array. It seems that index = i in the for loop is not updating the value of the index variable, even if the array contains other numbers lower than the 0 spot. Why?

```
public static int indexOfSmallestFrom(int[] array, int startIndex) {
    int smallest = array[startIndex];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
        int each = array[i];
        if (each < smallest) {
            smallest = each;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

edit: Here's the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your test code here
    int[] array = {99, 3, 1, 7, 4, 5, 2, 4};
    System.out.println("Smallest: " + indexOfSmallestFrom(array, 1));
}
```

It works correctly every time EXCEPT when the startIndex variable passed to the method call is 2! When a 1 is passed as above, it correctly returns 2, when 3 is passed, it correctly returns 6, etc. ???

Comment: `int index = 0;` should be `int index = startIndex` or else if you start on the smallest number the loop condition is never met and the `index` remains at `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you pass `startIndex = 2` into the function, we have `smallest = array[startIndex] = 1` in this case, and your code initializes `int index = 0;`. However, in your `for` loop, you have:

```
for (int i = startIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
  int each = array[i];
  if (each < smallest) {
    smallest = each;
    index = i;
  }
}
```

Since your `smallest` was initialized to the number at position `startIndex` but not your `index`, and the fact that `startIndex` happened to be the index of the smallest number, your `if (each < smallest)` will never be entered, meaning that `index` will stay at `0`.

To fix this, either change `int index = 0;` to `int index = startIndex;` OR you can change the condition in the `if` statement to `if (each <= smallest)` and your code should work fine (note that if you do this, it will return the last index if multiple minimums are present in the array).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, may be the smallest value is in 0 place in your case. But you should change index = startingIndex. Because that is where you are comparing items from.

```
public static int indexOfSmallestFrom(int[] array, int startIndex) {
    int smallest = array[startIndex];
    int index = startIndex;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
        int each = array[i];
        if (each < smallest) {
            smallest = each;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Or change < to <=

```
public static int indexOfSmallestFrom(int[] array, int startIndex) {
    int smallest = array[startIndex];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
        int each = array[i];
        if (each <= smallest) {
            smallest = each;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: I did this, and it worked, but I just want to understand this way because it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Why does it not make sense to you?

Comment: Thats because when you pass 6 it doesnt go inside if condition.. else you will have to change < to <= in if condition

Comment: Hope you undersyand it

Comment: Yes, @JavaDev is right.  If the starting position is the right answer, then you won't go in the `if`.  The problem with this is that `index` is not set correctly in your version for the case where `smallest` is set to the right answer initially.  You need to change that, so that `index` is correct if you never enter the `if`. That is the change that @JavaDev has made here.

Comment: `<=` makes sense because if it is equal, it means you have hit the smallest number and you want the index of that not skip over it.

Comment: @MehranB - it also works to set `index` to the position of the initial `smallest` value, as @JavaDev does in his first example.  Both of these are good answers.  I prefer the first.  One optimization could be made to it though.  The `for` loop could start at `i=startIndex+1`, since the first iteration will never do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Because the value in position 2 is the SMALLEST value (it's 1), hence the if condition is never entered :).